# mac mount_ftp with username @ sign

Tags: macos, ftp, terminal, mount

I have a problem with the Mac mount_ftp program:

I am trying to mount an ftp server to a local mountpoint in order to copy some files. I used the mac mount_ftp program for this.

This works fine for anonymous FTP sites, but it does not work when I have to provide a username and password.

My syntax is: mount_ftp username:password@ftp://ftp.name /path/to/mountpoint/

The program does something for around 30 seconds, then "echo $?"  gives exit status 13.

I think the problem is that my username has a "@" symbol in it (the FTP site uses email addresses as passwords). How do I pass the username and password arguments to mount_ftp separately?

I tried the -i option to mount_ftp - that does not work either.

Mac support sucks for this - they apparently do not support anything to do with the terminal ("Advanced Usage....")

Alex

Comment: Use the "-i" option and it will ask for username and password interactively.

Comment: "I tried the -i option to mount_ftp - that does not work either." - fourth line from the bottom of the original post

Comment: I was hoping you might try again and define "doesn't work" a bit better...

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to do this is to use %-encoding for the username (and password, and any other elements in the URL that conflict with URL syntax). Also, the `username:password@` bit goes after `ftp://`:

```
mount_ftp ftp://user%40emaildomain.com:password@ftp.name/ /path/to/mountpoint/
```

...but actually this doesn't work either, because mount_ftp doesn't properly %-decode the elements -- in the example I gave, it would actually send `user%40emaildomain.com` as the username.

This is a bug, and in principle should be reported to Apple. But I doubt they'd bother to fix it. This is not because they don't support anything to do with the Terminal; this exact same bug appears if you try to do the mount via the Finder. It's because they don't consider FTP support a high priority. Apple's FTP mounter has been buggy from the start. Back in the early days (10.0, 10.1, etc) it used to cause kernel panics -- I *think* it's stopped doing that, but frankly I haven't used it so long I'm not really sure. Apple's attitude seems to be (and I completely agree with this) that FTP is an ancient, crufty, and inherently broken protocol, and improving support for it is a waste of time.

That said, while the FTP mounter in OS X isn't very good, there is a (Terminal) `ftp` command that works just fine:

```
ftp ftp://user%40emaildomain.com:password@ftp.name/
```

...so this is actually a case where the Terminal interface works better than the GUI version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can ftp in to the server, but I was hoping to mount the server locally and copy files from there. The goal is to download files modified in the last 7 days. I could not get this to happen quickly without mounting locally (or perhaps learning the FTP syntax). Equally, I can't rely on having rsync installed on the server.

Comment: Would something like [FTPsync](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ftpsync/) work? (Note that I haven't tested whether it handles %-encoded usernames properly.)

Comment: I had a look, but the Documentation page returned 404 - not found, so I can't say if it would work.  I only want to download files with certain extensions (e.g. .zip) and of a certain age. From what I can see, the default behaviour of FTPsync is to make two hard disks mirror each other.